# What is the order of sequence when running a Spring Web MVC project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When running a Spring MVC project how is it executed in exact terms? What are the order of sequences? I've attached some code that I am working on. It's hard to tell for a beginner the exact sequence of the files. For example, localhost:8080 returns "Welcome to Spring MVC" which is in the `index.jsp` file. I've used Apache tiles to make `default.jsp` the template and I integrated `index.jsp` into it. If anyone could help explain to me the order of sequence spring goes through it would be appreciated, thanks.

web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>



<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatch-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.stevenhawk.jba.controller"></context:component-scan>

<!--======== USED TO CREAT A BEAN FOR TILESCONFIGURE CLASS IN SPRING ============ -->

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--================ USED TO INTEGRATE APACHE TILES WITH SPRING ======================= -->

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
```

IndexController.java

```
package com.stevenhawk.jba.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

/*
 * This is a controller that gets sent to if the url extension ends with"/index",
 * The "index" in the return statement corresponds to the "index" in general.xml file. 
 */


    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(){
        return "index"; 
    }


}
```

general.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<!--====== GENERAL XML IS USED TO SPLIT UP INDEX.JSP INTO 4 SEPERATE FILES =========== -->
<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/layout/default.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="index" extends="common">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Java Blog Aggregator" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="current" value="index"/>
</definition>

<definition name="users" extends="common">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Users" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/users.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="current" value="users"/>
</definition>

<definition name="user-detail" extends="common">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="User-detail" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/user-detail.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="current" value="users"/>
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Hello From Spring Web MVC
```

default.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<%@ include file="../layout/taglib.jsp"%>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" /></title>
</head>
<body>

<tilesx:useAttribute name="current" />

<div class="container">
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span
                class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href='<spring:url value="/"/>'>JBA</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="${current == 'index' ? 'active' : '' }">
                       <a href='<spring:url value="/"/>'>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="${current == 'users' ? 'active' : '' }">
                       <a href='<spring:url value="/users.html">
                     </spring:url>'>Users</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"></tiles:insertAttribute>
    <br></br>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"></tiles:insertAttribute>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Spring documentation address your question http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: What do you mean by _order of sequence_?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of documentation in the web to help you.

This could be a nice read for you :
http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html

The other source you can refer to is :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm

Comment: I've looked at the MVC section in tutorial point, but it didn't answer all the questions i had. Ill definitely look at dzone though, thank you..